# implementing mouseClicked in my code

Tags: java, mouseclick-event, game-development

This is my first time coding a game in Java. I am creating a RPG game. I have been successful in moving my character with the arrow keys using the KeyListener function. However, I have been trying to move my character   toward my mouse when its clicked in the window. I have figured out It can be done using the mouseClicked function but I cant seem to implement it in my code. I have been trying to understand the proper approach of laying it out but all the different codes on the internet have confused me more and more. I am uploading my player class with the little code I have on mouseAdapter. Any help with implementing it will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;



public class Player implements KeyListener {

private int x,y;
private SpriteSheet ss;
private boolean up = false, down = false, left= false, right = false;
public boolean mouseActive = false;  // mouse

public Point mouse;  // mouse

private final int SPEED = 3;


public Player( int x, int y, SpriteSheet ss) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.ss = ss;
}

public void tick() {
if(up) {
  y-=SPEED;
}

if (down) {
  y+=SPEED;
}

if (left){
  x-=SPEED;
}

if (right) {
  x+=SPEED;
}
}

public void render( Graphics g) {
g.drawImage(ss.crop(0,0,16,16), x, y, 16* Game.SCALE, 16* Game.SCALE, null);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
  up = true;

}
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
  down = true;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
  left = true;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
  right = true;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M) {     // mouse
  mouseActive = true;
}

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
  up = false;
}
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
  down = false;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
  left = false;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
  right = false;
}

if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M) {
  mouseActive = false;
}

}

 //  this is where I have been trying to add mouseClicked function to my code



 addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {

 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  mouse = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY() - 25);

  if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && !mouseActive) {
    x = mouse.x;
    y = mouse.y;
  }
  }
  });



}
```

Compilation errors:
5 errors found:

File: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java  [line: 11]
Error: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java:11: Player is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener

File: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java  [line: 18]
Error: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Point
location: class Player

File: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java  [line: 112]
Error: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java:112: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MouseEvent
location: class Player

File: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java  [line: 113]
Error: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java:113: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Point
location: class Player

File: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java  [line: 115]
Error: /Users/welcome/Documents/Player.java:115: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable MouseEvent
location: class Player

Comment: Does it even move? What happens if you print something to console before the `x = mouse.x` part? do you see that on the stdout?

Comment: My program worked fine and the character moved with the arrow keys before I had added the code regarding the click function. The code with the mouseClicked part did not compile. It gives the cannot find symbol error for almost every word in that part.

Comment: May be you need to change your approach.  Instead of moving your character based on the state of the keys, you move your character towards a x/y location.  So a keystroke would set the character's position to be an offset from where the character currently is and the mouse would be an absolute position...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think that's what the OP wants to achieve, user, can you post the compilation error that you get? it's most likely a problem with your braces.

Comment: Yes thats one way of doing it but again I cant seem to figure out the right Syntax. A bit more detail will be helpful?

Comment: `does not override abstract method keyTyped` there is your problem. Since it can't implement the class it can't resolve the next variables that rely on it.

Comment: Oh. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Implement the method like you did `keyPressed`.  Also make sure you add the imports for `java.awt.Point` and `java.awt.MouseEvent`

Comment: Your Player class implements KeyListener and was added with addKeyListener (to something). Make it implement MouseListener and add it with addMouseListener, the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This is proof of concept.  The idea is that the character will always be trying to move towards a given point (in this case `target`).

The keyboard controlling elements are designed to move the target a prescribed distance away from the current players position while they are pressed.

The mouse controlling element simple moves the target to the mouse clicked location.

The main engine simply tries to drive the character to that point.

In this example, keyboard actions override mouse actions

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MoveMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MoveMe();
    }

    public MoveMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Surface());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum KeyControl {

        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    public class Surface extends JPanel {

        private Character character;
        private Point target;

        private int xDelta = 2;
        private int yDelta = 2;

        private Set<KeyControl> keyControls;

        public Surface() {
            keyControls = new HashSet<>(4);
            character = new Character(new Rectangle(95, 95, 10, 10));
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    processKeyCommands();
                    if (target != null) {
                        Rectangle bounds = character.getBounds();
                        Point cp = new Point(bounds.getLocation());
                        cp.x += bounds.width / 2;
                        cp.y += bounds.height / 2;

                        if (!cp.equals(target)) {
                            if (cp.x != target.x) {
                                if (target.x < cp.x) {
                                    cp.x -= xDelta;
                                    if (cp.x < target.x) {
                                        cp.x = target.x;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    cp.x += xDelta;
                                    if (cp.x > target.x) {
                                        cp.x = target.x;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (target.y != cp.y) {
                                if (target.y < cp.y) {
                                    cp.y -= yDelta;
                                    if (cp.y < target.y) {
                                        cp.y = target.y;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    cp.y += yDelta;
                                    if (cp.y > target.y) {
                                        cp.y = target.y;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            bounds.x = cp.x - bounds.width / 2;
                            bounds.y = cp.y - bounds.height / 2;

                            if (bounds.x < 0) {
                                bounds.x = 0;
                            } else if (bounds.x + bounds.width > getWidth()) {
                                bounds.x = getWidth() - bounds.width;
                            }
                            if (bounds.y < 0) {
                                bounds.y = 0;
                            } else if (bounds.y + bounds.height > getHeight()) {
                                bounds.y = getHeight() - bounds.height;
                            }
                        } else {
                            target = null;
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }

            });
            timer.start();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    target = e.getPoint();
                }
            });

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "pressUp");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "pressDown");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "pressLeft");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "pressRight");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "releaseUp");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "releaseDown");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "releaseLeft");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "releaseRight");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("pressUp", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.UP, true));
            am.put("pressDown", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.DOWN, true));
            am.put("pressLeft", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.LEFT, true));
            am.put("pressRight", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.RIGHT, true));
            am.put("releaseUp", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.UP, false));
            am.put("releaseDown", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.DOWN, false));
            am.put("releaseLeft", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.LEFT, false));
            am.put("releaseRight", new KeyStateAction(keyControls, KeyControl.RIGHT, false));
        }

        protected Point createTargetBasedOnCharacter() {
            target = new Point();
            Rectangle bounds = character.getBounds();
            target.x = bounds.x + bounds.width / 2;
            target.y = bounds.y + bounds.height / 2;
            return target;
        }

        protected void processKeyCommands() {
            if (keyControls.contains(KeyControl.UP)) {
                Point target = createTargetBasedOnCharacter();
                target.y -= xDelta;
            } else if (keyControls.contains(KeyControl.DOWN)) {
                Point target = createTargetBasedOnCharacter();
                target.y += xDelta;
            }
            if (keyControls.contains(KeyControl.LEFT)) {
                Point target = createTargetBasedOnCharacter();
                target.x -= xDelta;
            } else if (keyControls.contains(KeyControl.RIGHT)) {
                Point target = createTargetBasedOnCharacter();
                target.x += xDelta;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (target != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fillOval(target.x - 5, target.y - 5, 10, 10);
            }
            character.render(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Character {

        private Rectangle bounds;

        public Character(Rectangle bounds) {
            this.bounds = bounds;
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        public void render(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fill(getBounds());
        }

    }

    public class KeyStateAction extends AbstractAction {

        private final Set<KeyControl> keyControls;
        private final KeyControl keyControl;
        private final boolean pressed;

        private KeyStateAction(Set<KeyControl> keyControls, KeyControl keyControl, boolean pressed) {
            this.keyControls = keyControls;
            this.keyControl = keyControl;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pressed) {
                keyControls.add(keyControl);
            } else {
                keyControls.remove(keyControl);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This example makes use of the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which provides better control over the level of focus required to trigger the key events.

I also decouple the entity (`Character`) from the controls.  This is, the keyboard and mouse controls and managed by the `Surface`, as, IMHO, the player entity should have no idea about.  This centralises the controls and means that the character can be moved by whatever input you want to add it it...